# How to display transition messages in site page only

Tags: php, expressionengine

Iam developing my site in expression engine and in expression engine if we logout then a transition screen will appear with a message '**you are logged out**' in a different page rather than in site page,

But what I want is I need to display that message in my site page itself,how can I achieve this,can anyone help me.

I have tried to design user custome message template under design in controller pannel but I think there is an option than this,suggest me please

Comment: For future reference you may prefer asking ExpressionEngine questions on the relevant Stack Overflow area: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Two approaches that I can think of...

Submitting the logout via Ajax, and then refreshing the relevant areas of the page to reflect login/logout status. You just have to access `http://example-domain.com/?ACT=14` URL

Or using [Custom System Messages](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/custom-system-messages) to better customise the resulting page that appears once logged out.

Comment: As I said in my question,cont we get the user custome message with {embed="global/header"}..??

Comment: The default ExpressionEngine (system) templates are painful and only really useful as a basic single page message (as they are by default), trying to use any ExpressionEngine tags, including embeds normally leads to frustration and being unsuccessful. You basically cannot do anything more with them that what's there by default (besides adding more inline styling).